# Laravel Mix code splitting broken in safari

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I have a dynamic importer component that imports different Vue components dynamically:

```
<template>
    <component :is="componentLoader" v-bind="props"></component>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            file: {
                type: String,
                default: () => null
            },
            props: {
                type: Object,
                default: () => {}
            }
        },
        name: "loader",
        computed: {
            componentLoader () {
                return () => import(`./cards/${this.file}`);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I use it like this:

```
<loader file="profile/skills/show"></loader>
```

It works perfectly if I run `nom run dev` and works in Chrome, Firefox, etc. even when I run `nom run prod`. However, in Safari, I get the following error (only after running prod):

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function () {
        return __webpack_require__("./resources/js/cards lazy recursive ^\\.\\/.*$")("./".concat(_this.file));
      }
Reason: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'modules[moduleId].call')
```

What's causing this? I have another project with a similar setup that works perfectly.